# Problem with saving something from RSS to txt file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, rss

My code is:

```
    import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://example.com/feed/"

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="xml")

items = soup.findAll('item')
counter = 2
for item in items:

    news_item = {}
    news_item['title'] = item.title.text
    news_item['description'] = item.description.text
    news_item['link'] = item.link.text


    for i in range(40):
        f = open("data.txt", "w+")
        counter += 1
        f.write("\n" + news_item['link'])
print(news_item['link'])
f.close()
```

when i'm trying to save news_item['link'] (link of a post in RSS) into my TXT file, it only writes 1 line and the last link. i want all the links in the each line in my TXT file. 
am i doing something wrong? how should i solve this issue

Comment: add the url too

Comment: The use of the `w+` file mode is likely at fault. Try switching to `a+`, and use a context manager.

Answer (score 0):

i just changed the code to :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "example.com/feed/"

resp = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="xml")

items = soup.findAll('item')
counter = 2
f = open("data.txt", "w+")

for item in items:

    news_item = {}
    news_item['title'] = item.title.text
    news_item['description'] = item.description.text
    news_item['link'] = item.link.text


    for i in range(1):
        counter += 1
        f.write("%s\n" % news_item['link'])
f.close()
```

and problem solved.